# Does the App engine (Standard Environment) servers that do not have any running instances (no traffic) are free?

Tags: google-app-engine

I want to know if the standard environment servers cost us while no traffic on them and the number of instances equal zero:

[image: Check the screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather off-topic on SO...

The standard environment bills in instance hours, not servers, see [Costs for standard environment instances](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/pricing#standard_instance_pricing) and [Instance hours](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/quotas#Instances).

Since you have no instances for that specific version (and assuming no instances are started for them during the billing cycle) that version will be, indeed, free. Even in there is some usage but the app remains overall under the daily free quota it'll still be free.

Answer (score 1):

You only pay for instances that are running.

Your screenshot shows a version of your code, which is not used by any instances.